# set up a MySQLdb connection object for multiple databases

Tags: python, database-connection, mysql-python

This question is likely noobish.

Instead of hardcoding the MySQLdb connection object: e.g,

```
db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','name','pwrd','db_name')
```

How do I set it up so I can specify the db_name (or any other part of the connection object) from a list or some other variable. E.g:

```
for NAME from list_of_names:
    db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'name', 'pwrd', NAME)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could setup a function that would return a new database connection based on the name passed in.

```
def get_db_connection(database_name):
    return MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'name', 'pwrd', database_name)
```

and then call get_db_connection whenever you needed to use a new database.

Better, you might try `db.select_db('my_new_databasename')` to switch from one database to another inside the same connection.  This assumes `db` is your connection object from the `MySQLdb.connect()` call.  This means you don't need to build a new connection each time.

Of note, creating database connections is expensive so try to avoid creating them and throwing them away at abandon.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a dictionary to store your connections objects

```
db_dict = {}
for NAME from list_of_names:
   db_dict[NAME] = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'name', 'pwrd', NAME)
```

Then you can access the db using the dictionary or assign a local to also point to the connection.

```
current_db = db_dict['db_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use lambdas for a quicker approach (quick in the sense of writing the code, also it feels more pythonic).

```
db = lambda(db): MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="user",passwd="pwd",db=db)
```

Then you can simply access the database by:

```
mydb = db("MyDb")
```